# Jquery not works for javascript innerHtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, using, innerhtml

**Please have a look on code written below. I am trying to have a multiple timer on one page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.countdown.css" media="all" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
    #defaultCountdown { width: 240px; height: 40px; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

      function LoadText()
      {  
      document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML = '<div id=\"defaultCountdown\" class=\"countdown\" rel=\"87401\">hjhg</div><br/><div id=\"defaultCountdown\" class=\"countdown\" rel=\"60\">hjgj</div><br/><div id=\"defaultCountdown\" class=\"countdown\" rel=\"1800\">hjhg</div><br/>';  
      } 
         </script> 

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="dd">
    </div>


     <script type="text/javascript">
          // Initialization 
      $(document).ready(function()
      {  

           var date = new Date();       
           $('div.#defaultCountdown').each(function()
            {             

               $(this).countdown
               ({
               until:parseInt($(this).attr("rel"),10),
               format:"DHMS",          
               expiryText:"Expired"
                })
            })   
        });      

         </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My code works fine when I create Divs Hardcoded. But when I load it through Ajax (For understanding of code, for the time being I am creating Divs using Function LoadText()), I am not able to get it displayed. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a class or unique IDs for the #defaultCountdown div.

Also this would confuse the selector engine since you are telling it to look for a class with a # sign in it:

```
$('div.#defaultCountdown').each(function()
```

Try changing it to a class and use:

```
$('div.defaultCountdown').each(function()
```

---

Update: Ok, the reason why your code isn't working is because the `LoadText()` function is never called. If you update your script to look like this, it will work ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/JYX8Q/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // This is needed to simulate the ajax call
    LoadText();

    // set up countdown timers
    var date = new Date();
    $('div.countdown').each(function() {
        $(this).countdown({
            until: parseInt($(this).attr("rel"), 10),
            format: "DHMS",
            expiryText: "Expired"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Just for more clarification, Id of Divs that I am creating is 'defaultCountdown' and the class is 'countdown'. I need a solution for referencing the Divs that I am creating using Ajax response text or through JavaScript innerHTML. If I write this divs hard coded that the same code works perfectly.

Comment: I updated my answer and included a demo of your script working.

Answer (score 2):

For one, you have this:

```
div.#defaultCountdown
```

which should be:

```
div#defaultCountdown
```

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't see you calling your LoadText function anywhere
2. ID's are required to be unique within a document, and your LoadText function does not respect that rule
3. Unrelated, but you don't need to escape those double quotes inside of your single quoted string in LoadText

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a timing issue. your jQuery code runs when the data is rendered to the page not after your ajax query completes. Make that a function rather than something to run on ready and call it after the ajax finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Your $('div.#defaultCountdown').each(function() loop runs once when the document is ready - if you subsequently add new divs using Ajax then you need to make sure you re-run your $('div.#defaultCountdown').each(function() code again now that new divs have been added.

The jQuery live() function is good for this.

Answer (score 0):

**The working Code if I am not using Ajax Response Text or JavaScript innerHTML.** Any solution in this direction will be appriciated. Please find below the modified code that is working. In this code I have **created the divs hardcoded**. Both the codes can be tested by copying this codes and saving it to html file.

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Count Down Timer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.countdown.css" media="all" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
#defaultCountdown { width: 240px; height: 40px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  

  **//function LoadText()
//  {
//  document.getElementById('divo').innerHTML='<div id="defaultCountdown" class="countdown" rel="87401">aaa</div><br/><div id="defaultCountdown" class="countdown" rel="60">bbb</div><br/><div id="defaultCountdown" class="countdown" rel="1800">ccc</div><br/>';
//  }**

  // Initialization 
  $(document).ready(function()
  {  
       var date = new Date();       
       $('div.countdown').each(function()
        {             

           $(this).countdown
           ({
           until:parseInt($(this).attr("rel"),10),
           format:"DHMS",          
           expiryText:"Expired"
            })
        })   
    });      

     </script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="divo">
<div id="defaultCountdown" class="countdown" rel="87401">aaa</div><br/><div id="defaultCountdown" class="countdown" rel="60">bbb</div><br/><div id="defaultCountdown" class="countdown" rel="1800">ccc</div><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please **edit** your question and add this information instead of providing an "answer".